# Какой JS WYSIWIG редактор вы посоветуете?

Tags: wysiwyg, редактор-текста, javascript, .net, редактор

Здравствуйте. Мне нужен хороший JS редактор для моих проектов. Главное, это подсветка кода на разных языках. Если такого нет, то подойдет даже обычное сохранение отступов, а дальше я с помощью плагинов JS расскрашу код сам. Также важна простота установки. Всем спасибо.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wysiwyg

Мне кажется вы немного запутались) Но, о чудо!, есть [Brackets][1], как раз для JS, поиграйтесь, может понравится)


  [1]: https://github.com/adobe/brackets

Comment: Что непонятного. Я просто хочу визуальный редактор для блога. С возможностью вставки подсвеченного кода.Редактор именно на JS а не под виндовс.

Comment: Всем, кого мучает тот же вопрос. Используйте CKEditor с плагином codehiglight. Инструкции по установке здесь: http://codingtools.ru/lessons/8/80. Вопрос считаю закрытым. Из-за крайней. неадекватности ответов, не принимаю никакой.

Comment: @gridsane У `Brackets` такая куча проблем, что лично я бы не стал его использовать с любой целью, кроме "поиграться".

Comment: Принимаю ответ nolka так-как там есть намек на редактор для сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок такой, будто Вам нужен редактор, всттраиваемый в веб-страницы, но по сути Вам нужен обычный редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса. Выбирайте сами:

- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) - отличный редактор не только js, но и многих других типов файлов. Чтот очень нравится - возможность навигации по коду с использованием клавиши Ctrl(Зажали Ctrl, наводим курсор на название метода, нажимаем левую кнопку мыши, и переходим к объявлению этого метода). Автокомплит для jquery у меня подключился автоматически.
- [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) - неплохой редактор, ориентирован на веб, основывается на eclipse. На счет крутости его сказать не могу, т.к. в основном использовал его для разработки на Python
- [Sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) - отличная замена блокноту. По умолчанию темная тема, подсветка синтаксиса, Code-folding, простейшая навигация по коду имеется
- [Web Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) - Не пользовался им, но зато пользовался PyCharm - ide для разработки на python - очень крутая ide. Скорее всего, webstorm такая же крутая, но для js. Платная, 30 дневный триал.

Если же Вам нужен именно WYSIWYG редактор для web, мне лично ну очень нравится [elRte](http://elrte.org/ru/)

Comment: Мне нужен именно редактор для браузера. И мне необходима возможность вставки кода с подсветкой.

Comment: Думаю, для elRte имеются плагины, позволяющие организовать подсветку синтаксиа :]

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужен именно редактор, то Sublime Text 2 Вам в руки, просто и надежно, но сублим и WYSIWIG редактор не особо сочетаются. Вам нужна IDE или тексторый редактор?

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю, в наше время лучше спрашивать какие именно опции интересуют, мне например важно:

- работа по фтп;
- работа с гитом;
- операции по авто подстановке и массовому смещению-изменению текста.